# Which installation does man find for a command name?

Tags: man

On Lubuntu 18.04, the default `awk` is `mawk`, and I found that `man awk` gave manpag of `mawk`

Then I installed `gawk`, and `awk` became `gawk`. and `man awk` gave manpag of `gawk`.

I wonder if that is the general case. In other words, when I run `man` on a command name, does it always provide the manpage of the  installation currently associated with the command name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is [update-alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) magic .

If, some commands come with same name, as in this case, `gawk` and `mawk` , and both has to be available by name of `awk`, then a `symlink` is created .
e.g.

```
/usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk
/etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
```

and same for man

```
/usr/share/man/man1/awk.1.gz -> /etc/alternatives/awk.1.gz
/etc/alternatives/awk.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/gawk.1.gz
```

man reads from `/usr/share/man/man1/awk.1.gz` ,and it being a symlink pointing to current installed command's manual , will open up current installed command manual

`/etc/alternatives` directory is used by [update-alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) to keep track of the alternatives currently in use .

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, when I run `man` on a command name, does it always provide the manpage of the installation currently associated with the command name?

With properly-configured programs, yes. (This should be the case at least for all packages originating in Debian.)

Packages which correctly set [alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) up for commands will associate the corresponding manpages to the alternative.

[`mawk`](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/loggerhead/users/vorlon/mawk/trunk/view/head:/debian/mawk.postinst) sets up an `awk` alternative with low priority (5), and associates the `nawk` command and both manpages (for `awk` and `nawk`). Thus whenever `mawk` is selected as the `awk` provider, it is also selected as the `nawk` provider, and its manpage is selected as the provider for the `awk` and `nawk` manpages.

[`gawk`](https://sources.debian.org/src/gawk/1:4.1.4+dfsg-1/debian/postinst/) also sets its alternatives up in this way, with a higher priority (10).

By default, alternatives are managed in automatic mode: whenever an alternative is installed or removed, the alternatives system chooses whichever available provider has the highest priority. When you install Lubuntu, only `mawk` is installed, so it is the only provider and is chosen by default. When you install `gawk`, two `awk` providers are available, and the alternatives system chooses `gawk` because it has the highest priority.

You can choose your own alternative using `update-alternatives --config awk`, which will allow you to force your own selection (by choosing one of the “manual mode” entries), or use whatever is the automatic selection (by choosing the “auto mode” entry).

The result of all this is a bunch of symlinks in `/etc/alternatives`; the `awk` executable is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/awk`, which is itself a symlink to the chosen provider. The current state of the system is stored in files under `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`, one per “main” alternative (`/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/awk` in this case). That’s an implementation detail of course and you should only use `update-alternatives` to interact with the alternatives system.